# php memcache key management

Tags: php, codeigniter, memcached

Hi I'm Integrating memcache in my codeigniter application,
My query change on the user selected values. some thing like this

```
$sql='select * from user where user_name="'.$name.'" and location='".$location."'";
$result = $this->memcached_library->get(md5($sql));
if(!$result ){
       /*  execute query and get $result    */
       $this->memcached_library->add(md5($sql), $result );
}else{
       return $result;
}
```

This is  my approach to handle the keys for each different query. But I have heard some where that md5() is not always unique.?

1> Is **md5()** always unique?

2> if md5() is not unique than what shoud be the other option....

3> what about **crc32()** is that unique??

Thanks....

Comment: If you need to use simple hashing mechanism, use `sha1()` instead of `md5()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A. Your SQL is wrong it should be

```
 $sql = "select * from user where user_name = '{$name}' and location = '{$location}'";
```

B. You code might have errors since MD5 is case sensitive

See

```
var_dump(md5("A"),md5("a"));
```

Output

```
string '7fc56270e7a70fa81a5935b72eacbe29' (length=32)
string '0cc175b9c0f1b6a831c399e269772661' (length=32)
```

Better Approach  us using `strtolower`

```
  $result = $this->memcached_library->get(md5(strtolower($sql)));
```

C, Is MD5 unique

> MD5 cannot guarantee total uniqueness, however there are approximately 3.402823669209387e+38 different values in a 32 digit hex value (16^32). That means that, assuming the math behind the algorithm gives a good distribution, your odds are phenomenally small that there will be a duplicate.

D. Better option is using `sha1`

```
$betterKey = "user" .  sha1(strtolower($sql));
               ^- identify request for each table
```

Comment: > Thanks it was a sample query only. I was confused about uniqueness of md5 .. I'll use your $betterKey for my key for memcache..

Answer (score 3):

MD5 is unique enough in your case.

**But:**

I used this technic for a while before dropping it. **Why?**

1. md5 is considered to be too fast for password hashing. But it is still a hashing function and when called each time you have to make a DB query, it might slow down your code. I've seen in the past that hashing the SQL query to generate a key was responsible 20% of the PHP execution time, which was huge.
2. If you need to delete or update a specific key, for example in your case if a user want to change his location and you want this change to be reflected as soon as possible, you'll have to rebuild the same DB query, hash it, to retrieve your key.

**The solution I prefer:**

Create simple, short, useful keys instead. Typically, use the method name from your model. If the method in your example is `User::getUser($name, $location)`, make your key:

```
$key = "User::getUser($name, $location)"
```

You won't need hashing at all, it will be clearer, and easier to manage keys.

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to the [Collision vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) of MD5. For practical, simple use you can forget about those. So MD5( uniqid() ) is unique. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

For generating hashes in use like SessionID, MD5() is fine.